# Range and list in Groovy not fully printed out

Tags: groovy, println

Can anyone explain why lines 1a and 2a do not print out the entire range but lines 1b, 1c, 2b and 2c do?

Script

```
println GroovySystem.version
def range = 1..5
printf "1a: range %s %n", range
printf "1b: range %s %n", range.toString()
printf "1c: range %s %n", range, ""
printf "2a: range %s %n", range.asList()
printf "2b: range %s %n", range.asList().toString()
printf "2c: range %s %n", range.asList(), ""
```

Output

```
3.0.9
1a: range 1 
1b: range 1..5 
1c: range 1..5 
2a: range 1 
2b: range 1..5 
2c: range 1..5
```

I am new to groovy but I would expect 1a and 1c to be the same (likewise for 2a and 2c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
def range = 1..5

printf "1a: range %s %n", range
printf "1b: range %s %n", 1,2,3,4,5    //same as 1a
printf "1c: range %s %n", *range, ""   //same as 1,2,3,4,5,""

printf "2a: range %s %n", range, ""
printf "2b: range %s %n", [range, ""]  //same as 2a
printf "2c: range %s %n", [range]
```

result

```
1a: range 1 
1b: range 1 
1c: range 1 
2a: range 1..5 
2b: range 1..5 
2c: range 1..5
```

all parameters to printf passed as a list.

so, if you passing just one parameter that is a list then every element of list considered as a separate parameter.

it means that `1a` and `1b` are equivalent

that's why all `1*` examples giving just a first element of a list (range)

`2c` shows a workaround for this

Comment: Thanks daggett. From your explanation and the printf signature https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object%5B%5D) it makes sense now.